# Can we have an infinite tree in this graph?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, trees, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-connectivity

Suppose that a graph has an infinite number of nodes set up as follows:
let $V_n=\{a_{n,1},a_{n,2},\dots,a_{n,n-1}\}\cup\{b_n\}$ be a set of $n$ nodes. Let $V=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty V_n$.

I am interested in graphs that can be built using nodes of V following the  condition:

> For every $n$, each $a\in\{a_{n,1},a_{n,2},\dots,a_{n,n-1}\}$ is
>   connected to some $a'\in V_{n-1}$ by an edge.

Note: for every $n$, $b_n$ can be connected to some element(s) of $V_{n-1}$ but is not mandatory.

An example of such graph is depicted in the following picture where the elements $a_{n,1},a_{n,2},\dots,a_{n,n-1}$ are the white nodes and $b_n$ is the blue node.

[image]

I want to prove the following

> **Claim:** There are only 2 types of graphs that can be built in this form: either a graph with an infinite connected sub-graph, or a graph
>   that is union of disjoint finite connected sub-graphs that start at
>   some $b_n$ and  all the other nodes are in $V_m$ with $m>n$.

A graph of the 1st type is depicted in the picture above and a graph of the 2nd type is depicted in the picture below:

[image]

I think that the claim is true (almost trivially), but I don't know much about Graph Theory and maybe this claim can be proved very easily with some very  well-know result in this area that I ignore. Any insight to prove this claim would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $G$ has no infinite connected component. 
On $i$th step let 
 
$G_i = \{b_i\} \cup \{a|a$ is white vertex above, reacheable from $b_i$ without going through other blue nodes$\}$ 
 
 then remove $G_i$ from G and continue. 
 Clearly $G_i$ is finite, has the only blue node and white nodes from above it, $\{G_i\}$ are disjoint. 
  
 To prove that $\{G_i\}$ is a partition required we only left to prove that every white node will be deleted. By induction we prove that after $i$th step every white vertex from $1..i+1$ levels has been deleted. 

 Let $a$ be an arbitrary white vertex from $(i+1)$th level. If $a$ was connected to another white from $i$th level it has been already deleted (as reachability is transitive). If it was not, it is connected to $b_i$ and will be deleted on $i$th step.

Comment: Thanks @Vladislav for your contribution (+1). Can you please explain what do you mean by "without going through other blue nodes"?

Comment: = there is a path from **b_i** to **a** that doesn't contain blue nodes except b_i

Comment: The thing is that it is possible to have $a\in V_6$ connected by a path to $b_4$ and $b_5$. Therefore $a\not\in G_4$ and  $a\not\in G_5$. Thus, by deleting $G_i$'s you will not be deleting this particular $a$.

Comment: I don' think I follow you. If, for instance, there is a path $a - a_x \in V_5 - b4$, it will be in $G_4$. If the only path from $a$ to $b_4$ is through $b_5$ it will be in $G_5$ (as $a$ is connected to $b_5$)

Comment: [First case illustration](https://i.imgur.com/O7wFzku.png) [Second case illustration](https://i.imgur.com/PcpSvgX.png)

Comment: In the first case illustration, join $b_4$ and $b_5$ with an edge. In this new case, $a\not \in G_4$ and $a\not \in G_5$.

Comment: How $a \notin G_4$? There is still a path $a - a' - b_4$, thus by definition $a \in G_4$ [Illustration](https://i.imgur.com/GnQEOKg.png)

Comment: Ok, I got the definition of $G_i$ now.

Answer (score 1):

For each $a_{n,i}$, is it adjacent to exactly one edge in $V_{n-1}$, or can it be adjacent to multiple edges?

If only one edge, then the picture on top is incorrect, but I believe the statement is true. It can be observed that each $a_{n,m}$ has a neighbor beneath it, and so its component must continue downward until it necessarily terminates at $b_i$ for some $i$, the only place it could stop. If some element of $V_i$ were also in this connected component, there must be a vertex $a_{j,k}$ with two neighbors of a lower level, a contradiction. Then there either exists an infinite component, or not, and therefore it is one of the two cases.

[[ If multiple edges are allowed, then it is easy to come up with a counterexample; just take your second picture and make $V_5$ complete to $V_4$. Then, the condition fails since there is no infinite connected component, but $b_4$ would be in the same connected component as $a_{4,1}$. ]]

Edit: The bracketed argument does not work. I believe that by picking the $b_n$ such that $n$ is smallest in each connected component, this claim can be shown.

I hope this helps.

Comment: From the condition and the first picture you can deduce that $a_{n,i}$ can be adjacent to multiple nodes in $V_{n-1}$.

Comment: How does it fail? The sets in partition don't have to be connected components of the graph.

Comment: Your second "counterexample" does not contradict the claim. In your scenario where you have $b_4$ in the same connected component as $a_{4,1}$, that component will start in some $b_i$ for $i=1,2,3$. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. To quote: "There are only 2 types of graphs that can be built in this form: either a graph with an infinite connected sub-graph, or a graph that is union of disjoint finite connected sub-graphs that start at some $b_n$ and all the other nodes are in $V_m$ with $m>n$". Note that in the counterexample, one connected component begins at $b_4$ and has vertices from $V_4$. Observe also that $4>4$ is a false statement. It's the $m>n$ condition that is crucial.

Comment: If you make $V_4$ complete to $V_5$, does that connected component not include the single vertex in $V_1$?

Comment: Oh, thats true. What I wrote is not a counterexample